# A convergent sum involving the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Let $\rho = \beta+i\gamma$ be a non-trivial zero of $\zeta(s)$. [Davenport](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-5927-3) (see bottom of page 81) claims that the sum $$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho}$$ converges because one can group together the terms between $\rho$ and its complex conjugate $\bar{\rho}$ such that
$$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho}=\sum_{\gamma>0} \left( \frac{1}{\rho}+ \frac{1}{\bar{\rho}}  \right) \leq \sum_{\gamma>0} \frac{2}{\vert \rho \vert^2},$$
which is known to converge. Why can the sum $\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho}$ be added term by term such that the terms involving $\rho$ and $\bar{\rho}$ can be paired together? Wouldn't we already have to assume that the sum converges unconditionally to show that its terms can be rearranged?

Comment: this is a type of summation of a conditionally convergent sum when you sum in some given specific order of the terms; here for example you can take the partial sums to be $s_n=\sum_{|\Im \rho| \le n}\frac{1}{\rho}$, or similarly by ordering $\rho_n$ in increasing order of the absolute value of their imaginary parts as $\rho_n, n=1,..$ where for conjugate $\rho$ you can take first the one with positive imaginary part, and again taking partial sums $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/\rho_n$; in both cases one gets convergence, but of course, one cannot renumber the $\rho$ arbitrarily and get convergence

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. So the proof only shows that $\sum_{\rho} \rho^{-1}$ converges conditionally? If so, under what "conditions" exactly?

Comment: as noted summing on $\rho$ in order of their magnitude works; so if you write $s_n=\sum_{|\Im \rho| \le n} 1/\rho$, that converges; note that it is known and easily proven that $\sum 1/\rho$ is not absolutely convergent

Comment: @Conrad Yes, because $\sum 1/\rho$ does not converge absolutely, the terms of the sum can not be arranged arbitrarily to achieve convergence. So why can the terms with $\rho$ and its conjugate be paired up in the sum $\sum 1/\rho$ to conclude that it in fact converges?

Comment: @Conrad It seems that there is some special condition that allows $\rho$ and its conjugate to be able to be paired up in $\sum 1/\rho$, despite that $\sum 1/\rho$ is not absolutely convergent. I want to figure out what those conditions are.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question; we choose to consider the series defined as above, in other words the partial sums are $s_n=\sum_{|\Im \rho| \le n}$; since $\rho, \bar \rho$ have same absolute value of the imaginary part, they both belong to the sum defining $s_n$ and conversely, any root has its conjugate there, so we can pair them up and estimate $s_n$ using that and show that $s_n$ converges so the series converges by the definition of convergence of a series (partial sums converge); if you want to phrase it that way, we use that $|\Im \rho|=|\Im \bar \rho|$

Comment: @Conrad I believe I see the argument. Because $\vert \Im \rho \vert=\vert \Im \bar{\rho} \vert$, the terms with $\rho$ and $\bar{\rho}$ in the sum can be paired up because the sum is taken in order of increasing absolute value of the imaginary part of the zeros?

Comment: correct - and again note that we choose to take the sum that way (I mean it is of course natural to do so, but it is still a choice)